# How to apply AR into live video stream?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

What are the possible methods to create an AR solution like this?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zD_YQBaZEY

Answer (score 0):

You need AR devices and AR SDK and 3D engine, for example, iPhone + ARKit + Unity(Unreal).
But the content shown in your youtube link is unlikely AR content, it made by some kind of after effect software.

OK I make a simple search, here:[tracking-3d-camera-movement](https://helpx.adobe.com/hk_en/after-effects/using/tracking-3d-camera-movement.html), this is what you want I think.

Comment: Yes. i'm creating AR solutions using Unity and AR SDK but this is different AR solution. Because they use this in live video stream. I need to know how to apply AR into live stream video like above link.